# Can infinitives serve as direct objects?

Tags: infinitives, direct-objects

In the sentences *Jack wants food* and *Jack wants to eat*, it seems like *food* and *to eat* both serve as direct objects of the verb *wants*. Can a verb in the infinitive serve as a direct object in a sentence like this, or does it play some other role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, infinitive is one kind of verbals that can function as a noun, an adjective, or an adverb. > http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/infinterm.htm

One of the functions of nouns is it can be the direct object of a verb. >http://www.english-for-students.com/Noun-Functions.html

In the sentence *Jack wants to eat*, the infinitive *to eat* functions as a *noun* because
it is the object of the finite verb *wants*. A direct object answers the questions what? or who?

Therefore, yes. I hope this explanation helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that verbs could function as nouns, but I thought that was only when they were in the "ing" form, as in _Jack enjoys eating._ Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: Though _Jack wants food_ and _Jack wants to eat_ have fairly similar-looking structures, and 'to eat' would be called a direct object in this construction by most people, there are very large differences below the surface. The noun-as-DO structure is simple; the verb + to-infinitive construction has many variants. Jack has food / Jack has to eat. *Jack seems food / Jack seems to eat. Jack wastes food / *Jack wastes to eat. I believe the 'to-infinitive as DO' analysis is far from satisfactory.